# Discord displays @deleted-role while the role is still avalible

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I got this problem when the discord bot I write with discord.js shows a role as `@deleted-role`, The role itself is still available but the bot says deleted role. I tried to test it with another role same here are the images of the and the code:

```
if (message.content.includes("test"))
  return message.channel.send("<@&" + 855179067388461076 + "> why is that ");
```

The result

[image]

The role

[image]

Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: if you type `<@&855179067388461076>` into your discord does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use an integer (`855179067388461076`) as a snowflake. It should be a string. As this number is greater than 53 bits ([`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)) JavaScript has difficulty interpreting it. It can only safely represent integers between -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Max safe integer | `9007199254740992` |
| Your integer | `855179067388461076` |
| Your integer becomes | `855179067388461000` |

And there is no role with the ID of `855179067388461000`. To solve this, make sure you only use strings as snowflakes:

```js
message.channel.send("<@&" + "855179067388461076" + "> why is that")

// OR
const roleId = "855179067388461076"
message.channel.send("<@&" + roleId + "> why is that")
```

```js
console.log('<@&' + 855179067388461076 + '> why is that ')
// => <@&855179067388461000> why is that
```