# discord.js v13 permissions.has() function not working (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has'))

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to program a `ban` command for my Discord bot. I have this line where the bot should check if a user has the Administrator permission. If the user that should get banned has them, the bot doesn't ban the user and crashes. When I try to run this command I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')
```

I don't understand why. Noone I asked could help me, I found nothing online, so I hope I can find here help.

My Code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id == 589850931785498624)) {
    return message.reply("You don't have the perms.");
  }

  const mention = message.mentions.users.first();

  if (!mention) {
    return message.reply('You need to tag a user!');
  }

  if (mention.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_CHANNELS)) {
    return message.reply("You can't ban an Administrator!")
  }

  //message.guild.members.ban(mention);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "ban",
  aliases: ["b"],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')"* means that `mention.permissions` is `undefined`. It's because your `mention` variable is a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) and only `GuildMember`s have [`permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions).

Another error is that you try to check if the `role.id` is equal to a number/integer but snowflakes (like `589850931785498624`) [should always be strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230683/6126373) as these are greater than the [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

```js
module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.id == '589850931785498624'))
    return message.reply("You don't have the perms.");

  const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

  if (!mentionedMember)
    return message.reply('You need to tag a user!');

  if (mentionedMember.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_CHANNELS))
    return message.reply("You can't ban an Administrator!");

  message.guild.members.ban(mentionedMember);
};
```