# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') discord v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I keep getting that error no matter what I do.

This is my code

```js
      let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Bazaar")
      .setColor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215))
      .addFields(...fields)
      
      const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(1069212856278581258)
      const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(1098111857367187506);
      //const Channel = client.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "some-amazing-bots");
    //  client.channels.cache.get(1098111857367187506).send({embeds: [embed]});
      logChannel.send({embeds: [embed]});
      inRequest = false;
```

I tried to do this way but nothing worked.

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(1069212856278581258)
const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(1098111857367187506);
```

Comment: Does it also happen when you fetch the channel instead of getting it from cache?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using integers as snowflakes. Snowflakes [should always be strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230683/6126373). If you store these IDs as numbers, JS has difficulty interpreting them. Any number greater than the [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) becomes a different number, and if you provide a different ID, again, every available guild gets fetched.

Try to run the following code below. If your guild's ID is `1069212856278581258` and you try to log this number, `1069212856278581200` is logged because it's larger than 2<sup>53</sup> - 1:

```js
console.log(1069212856278581258)
```

When you try to get the guild using `client.guilds.cache.get(1069212856278581258)`, you're actually looking for a guild with the ID of `1069212856278581200` in the cache and that returns `undefined`.

It's the same with `client.channels.cache.get(1098111857367187506)`. `1098111857367187506` will become `1098111857367187500` so it will return `undefined` again. `undefined.send()` doesn't exist that's why it throws the error.

To solve this, you'll always need to use strings instead of integers if you're using IDs in discord.js:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('1069212856278581258');
const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get('1098111857367187506');
logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Related answers: 
[Discord displays @deleted-role while the role is still avalible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230554/discord-displays-deleted-role-while-the-role-is-still-avalible/68230683#68230683) 
[discord.js v13 permissions.has() function not working (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70634214/discord-js-v13-permissions-has-function-not-working-typeerror-cannot-read-pr/70634977#70634977)

Comment: I tried doing that but now I get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')