# Fetching a guild using its ID returns every available guild in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I am trying to fetch a guild using its ID which the bot is in, but it doesn't seem to work. Whenever I run this, it outputs a collection of every guild the client is in.

`e` is read from a JSON file, the `id` property is a direct copy from the server.

```js
client.guilds.fetch(e.id).then((guild) => {
  // logs every available guild instead of the one where id is e.id
  console.log(guild)
})
```

Here are my intents and partials

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
  ],
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], 
});
```

Comment: What is `e`? It might not be what you think

Comment: e is read from a json file the id property is a direct copy id from the server

Comment: i already checked and they are equal @MrMythical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options; either your `id` is `undefined` or it's a number.

As `fetch` only accepts a [`GuildResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/GuildResolvable), or a [`FetchGuildOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FetchGuildOptions)/[`FetchGuildsOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FetchGuildsOptions) object as its parameter. If you pass something else, it's just ignored and every available guild gets fetched (just like you mentioned).

I think your `id` is a snowflake, as you mentioned that it's coming from a JSON file. Snowflakes [should always be strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230683/6126373). If you store these IDs as numbers, JS has difficulty interpreting them. Any number greater than the [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) becomes a different number, and if you provide a different ID, again, every available guild gets fetched.

For example, if your snowflake is `921423246421811231`, it becomes `921423246421811200`. Try to run the snippet below, you'll see that it logs the second number, not what the value of `e.id`:

```js
let e = {
  id: 921423246421811231
}

console.log(e.id)
```

To solve this, make sure you store the `id` as a string in your JSON file:

```json
{
  "id": "921423246421811231"
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didnt work now somehow trying it again after your message has made it work, the only problem is this error now :(
https://pastebin.com/a9vtezag

Comment: What's your guild ID? `774342001776132100`? That double zero at the end suggests that it still stored as a number.

Comment: Wait you're right thanks so much i didn't realize, its supposed to be a 6 i think reading and writing the json lowered it, thanks

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but I think that might be the fix

Comment: Yes it works as expected now

Comment: That's great :)