# I'm having keep getting and error while using embeded messages because "cannot read property 'send' of undenifide"

Tags: javascript, discord.js, replit

I'm trying to make my bot send embededmessages and each time I send the message it gives me an error like this "cannot read property 'send' of undenified".Here is my code

```
else if(message.content == "testing") {
      let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(832075875612491789)
      const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('v1.1 test')
        .setThumbnail('https://i0.wp.com/www.mysabah.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2006/06/252.jpg?fit=640%2C392&ssl=1')
      channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    }
```

Comment: What's *undenifi(e)d(e)*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord displays @deleted-role while the role is still avalible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230554/discord-displays-deleted-role-while-the-role-is-still-avalible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your channel isn't defined, presumably because you're using an integer to get it instead of a string.

Snowflakes in Discord are stored as string, so instead of fetching the channel using a number, use the following:

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("832075875612491789");
```

Answer (score 0):

To send message in a particular channel, or calling channel by id, to store the channel id we need strings, use this

```js
           
else if(message.content == "testing") {
      let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("832075875612491789")
      const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('v1.1 test')
        .setThumbnail('https://i0.wp.com/www.mysabah.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2006/06/252.jpg?fit=640%2C392&ssl=1')
      channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    }
```

everything was fine but you should make changes in the line

```js
     let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("832075875612491789")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
else if(message.content == "testing") {
      let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("832075875612491789")
      const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('v1.1 test')
        .setThumbnail('https://i0.wp.com/www.mysabah.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2006/06/252.jpg?fit=640%2C392&ssl=1')
      channel && channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    }
```