# awaitMessages doesn't collect slash commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a `botReady.js` file that executes as soon as the bot is ready. Within the file, the section under `client.channels.fetch` is for a channel in which a bump bot is run. You can bump your server with `/bump` on the public website.

Within my own bot, I've made a function that reminds people that it's possible to bump again, so basically, it's a bump reminder. The problem I'm facing is that with `channel.awaitMessages`, if I execute the `/bump` slash command, `awaitMessages` doesn't work. I've tried just sending a message and when I do this the rest of the code does execute.

Maybe `awaitMessages` doesn't pick up bot messages? Or is there a way to pick up slash commands from other bots?

```
client.channels.fetch('953344670094737418').then(channel => {
        
        channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
            roleId = 965589664914354196
            let lastMessage = messages.first();
            
            if (Date.now() - lastMessage.createdTimestamp > 0) {var timeoutTime = 7200000 - (Date.now() - lastMessage.createdTimestamp)} 
            else {var timeoutTime = 7320000}

            async function myFunction() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    channel.send("It's time to bump again! \n <@&965589664914354196>").then(() => {
                        //Wait for message to be sent and than continue. Doesnt pick up slash commands.
                        channel.awaitMessages({ max: 1 }).then(message => {
                            console.log("Succesfully Bumped!")
                            timeoutTime = (7320000)
                            myFunction()
                        })
                    })                      
                }, timeoutTime);
            }

            myFunction()
          })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a `filter` to filter out messages coming from a bot, `awaitMessages` does pick up these. The problem is that a slash command is not a message, so you can't use `awaitMessages` here.

However, you can create a new [`InteractionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/InteractionCollector) that only collects slash commands. Just make sure its type is `APPLICATION_COMMAND`:

```js
const { InteractionCollector } = require('discord.js');
const { InteractionTypes } = require('discord.js/src/util/Constants.js');

// ... more code here

channel
  .send(`It's time to bump again! \n <@&965589664914354196>`)
  .then(() => {
    let collector = new InteractionCollector(client, {
      channel: channel,
      filter: (i) => i.commandName === 'bump',
      interactionType: InteractionTypes.APPLICATION_COMMAND,
      max: 1,
    });

    collector.on('collect', (i) => {
      console.log(`Successfully bumped with command "${i.commandName}"`);
      timeoutTime = 7320000;
      myFunction();
    });
  });
```

PS: You will need to [store snowflakes as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230683/6126373) as JS will replace the last digits with zeroes. So, it should be `roleId = '965589664914354196'`